# Why doesn't QFileDiaglog method directory show the current directory?

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

When I start the program, the filedialog is in a certain directory. Then I move to other directories and select some files. Once the files are selected I try to get that current directory from which the files are selected. But it doesn't return me the current directory, it returns me the original directory which the filedialog was initially in when the program was started. The code snippet is as below:

```
QFileDialog * fileDialog = new QFileDialog(this);
fileDialog->setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
QListView* list = fileDialog->findChild<QListView*>("listView");
if(list)
{
    list->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
}
QTreeView* tree = fileDialog->findChild<QTreeView*>();
if(tree)
{
    tree->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
}
if(fileDialog->exec())
{
    if(fileDialog->selectedFiles().size()>0)
    {
        QDir dir = fileDialog->directory();
        fileDialog->update();
        qDebug()<<dir.absolutePath();
    }
}
```

Could you say me what mistake I am doing? How can get the absolute path of the directory in which the filedialog is currently in?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using such a complicated approach and not the [one call static method?](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileNames)

Comment: Why do you think that you need to mess with the internal implementation of a file dialog, just in order to select multiple files? Doesn't this code look abhorrent? Never mind that a file dialog nominally has no internal Qt implementation - you're probably running on a system where it does, but on neither Windows nor OS X this would be nominally the case. The `setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles)` is sufficient. Why do you need those other hacks?

Comment: Why do you care what directory it is? As long as the returned files have either absolute paths, or relative paths in relation to `directory()`, you're OK and don't need to care which exact directory it really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QFileDialog has several static methods that do return the selected file and the current directory getExistingDirectory, getOpenFileName, getOpenFileNames, getSaveFileName. You might want to use one of these static functions. The other option is to subclass QFileDialog and override the exec method to return the current directory. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with static methods like others suggesting, but I think first you should fix memory leak!

Note that it you code you are creating a NEW `QFileDialog` that is why you get same directory every time. You use this  dialog only once and it is deleted when with `this` object (probably main window).

So either use static version or create a field in you main window class and create only one dialog and reuse it when needed.